# interceptApplication(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' is deprecated

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just upgrade AWSMobileClient from 2.6.8 to 2.7.0 and see the following line of warning message:

> 'interceptApplication(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' is deprecated: This method will be removed in the next minor version. Please update to use AWSMobileClient using `initialize`. Please visit https://aws-amplify.github.io for the latest iOS documentation.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(
        application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
        launchOptions)
}
```

It is not obvious to me what we should change `interceptApplication` to. There is indeed a `initialize` function. Should we just put that in `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: )` and return `true` always?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().initialize { (userState, error) in
        // ...
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too have have experienced the same issue this week. In the latest [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication), specifically the [initialization](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#initialization) section you will see it says:

> Open the AppDelegate of your Xcode project, or optionally in your View Controller viewDidLoad() and invoke the initialize routine

So what I did is go to AppDelegate and replace:

```
return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

With:

```
return true
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` in your main `UIViewController` call the initialization routine as per the docs:

```
import AWSMobileClient

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().initialize { (userState, error) in
        if let userState = userState {
            print("UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
        } else if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

You will then be able to use the new user state listener for your app's auth logic:

```
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().addUserStateListener(self) { (userState, info) in
    switch (userState) {
        case .guest:
            print("user is in guest mode.")
        case .signedOut:
            print("user signed out")
        case .signedIn:
            print("user is signed in.")
        case .signedOutUserPoolsTokenInvalid:
            print("need to login again.")
        case .signedOutFederatedTokensInvalid:
            print("user logged in via federation, but currently needs new tokens")
        default:
            print("unsupported")
    }
}
```

And you can now also use `getTokens`:

```
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().getTokens { (tokens, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error getting token \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    else if let tokens = tokens {
        print("id token: \(tokens.idToken!.tokenString!)")
        print("access token: \(tokens.accessToken!.tokenString!)")
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!